# Represent Set Difference then PartOf with best possible performance

Tags: c#, oop, math, optimization, set

I have a set of elements like this :

```
A = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I need to execute Set-Difference with `{j}` please notice j is always one element. The returned difference from `Aoj` needs to be checked if it is a PartOf Set `B`

How to achieve this in C# with best possible performance if this approach is repeated for > 100K times in each execution ?

Comment: Can you use bit vectors (which is to say that you represent each element of the set with one bit)?  This would work well given the example data you have, but can break down if you can't give each element a unique ordinal.  Bit vector efficiency is also reduced if ordinals get too sparse.

Comment: Well, what have you tried and what performance issues have you encountered?

Comment: Code something that _works_, then get a good profiler to determine where most of the time is being spent and optimize that.  Anything more is speculation.

Comment: Its very easy thing to do and does not need codes , you can represent this in lists or arrays , I was asking about the most efficient way to do it @DStanley

Comment: I mean its very likely that lists would not deliver good performance, the only way  I can imagine is to use arrays but I want to see if there are out of the box ways by stackoverflow users @InBetween

Comment: Guys please stop voting-down its a good question in C# math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `BitArray`.  It will substantially outperform a hash for many use cases (just don't know enough specifically about yours).  You will need to assign an ordinal to each element of your set, for example, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  `BitArray` has `And`, `Or`, `Get`, `Set` operations, more.

Comment: Well I like your answer , can you specify more about Ordinal representation ?

Comment: You need to give each element of the set a unique ordinal number value.  If your set really looks like numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 ... then it can be as simple as using that number.  Otherwise, some formula might work.  If you know zero is never used, you could say that 1 -> 0, 2 ->1... i.e. ordinal(x)=x-1.

Comment: Still, depending on your context, you may have to assign a new (the next) ordinal for every element of the set that you see, using a mapping of elements to ordinal.  This lookup of element to ordinal may use a hash, but the math for the set difference and presence will be very fast.  All depends on your larger context as to what happens more often.

Comment: I meant to say how to perform these math operations on ordinal representation . In fact I don't have clue about that , can you please edit the question with simple code corresponds to the question ? @Erik

Comment: Ok, if understand the comment/question: you want to do a set difference, where you know that there are two sets, but the latter is constrained such that it has only one element.  I think that is a bit clear operation.  So, you can clone the first input if you need to, then clear the given bit from the second set.  The result should be the difference.  For PartOf, you want the intersection as an intermediate, so that is an `And` operation.  Then you test for empty set, which is `Equals` with a `BitArray` of zeros.